# Repositioning page layout with CSS

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries, page-layout

I have a problem where I wish to alter the positioning of webpage using CSS for a mobile view.  The current set up for desktop is a sidebar floated to the left and a textbox floated to the right.  The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="sidebar">...</div>
   <div id="textbox">...</div>
</div>
```

My dilemma is that on mobile devices I wish for the sidebar content to appear under the textbox and I am struggling to produce the CSS to do this.  I am using media queries to target smart phones eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px) {
  /* Target portrait smartphones */
}
```

Can anyone provide me with the CSS to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, in order to do that you should use it like this

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="textbox">...</div>
   <div id="sidebar">...</div>
</div>
```

The textbox first because you'll remove float for mobile. So the textbox goes first then the sidebar.

The css:

```
.textbox {
    width: ***px;
    float right;
}
.sidebar {
    width: ***px;
    float left;
}
@media screen and (max-width:479px) {
  /* Target portrait smartphones */
  .textbox, .sidebar {
     float: none;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to have `#sidebar` after `#textbox` in your html, this wont effect desktop viewing, and then for mobile you can just remove the floats:

```
@media screen and (max-width:479px) {
  #sidebar, #textbox {
    float: none;
  }
}
```